# How can I rename the placeholder of in filter of a DT datatable in R?

Tags: r, datatables, dt

```
library(DT)
data <- data.frame("Hi" = c("One","Two"), "Something" = c("A", "B"))
datatable(data, filter = 'top')
```

Translating a DT::datatable is nicely documented [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/004-i18n.html). But, I am having trouble translating the placeholder on filter showing "ALL" in the example above. Does anyone have an idea how to change this?

Comment: The DT filters have been implemented by Yihui Xie, one of the main authors of the package. They are not part of the **datatables** JavaScript library. So you can't use the `language` option for that. I may be wrong, but I think there's no way to change this "ALL" (except by modifying the source code of the package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but until they enable this in their API, you could always clean up with javascript afterwards:

```r
library(DT)
data <- data.frame("Hi" = c("One","Two"), "Something" = c("A", "B"))
datatable(
    data, filter = 'top',
    callback=JS('$(\'div.has-feedback input[type="search"]\').attr( "placeholder", "Alles" )')
)
```

Looks like this:

[image: changed placeholders]