# DT datatables R How to customize top/bottom column filter fields? (font size and texting/translation)

Tags: r, filter, datatables, translate, dt

I would like to customize the column filter for some datatables that I am generating in an RMarkdown script. **I'm looking for a way to**

1. **translate the "All" or apply the actual column names in the column filter fields**
2. **change the font size of the column filter fields**

The code below translates the entire fields of the datatable except the "All" field of the column filters.

```
    cars %>% datatable(filter="top", 
                       options = list(language = list(url = 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/i18n/de_de.json') ))
```

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap8ZX.jpg)

Alternatively, any mean to just apply the column name inside the column filter field would be interesting as well. [Something like this](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering), but in R...

I am also looking for a way to reduce the font size of the "All" of the column filter fields, but couldn't find a way yet.. The following code changes the font size of the remaining fields/table but not the column filters.

```
/* Data tables */

.datatables {
  margin: 2em 0em;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.datatables label {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.dataTables_length,
.dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_info,
.dataTables_paginate {
  font-size: 80%;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rename the placeholder of in filter of a DT datatable in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064500/how-can-i-rename-the-placeholder-of-in-filter-of-a-dt-datatable-in-r)

Comment: This solved my issue with the translation. Many thanks!! Do you have also any suggestions how to fix the font size? Thanks again!